# How to convert dd:hh:mm:ss format time into seconds in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, spreadsheet

I got some data in Excel and most of them are in the format of **hh:mm:ss**. So I can use the formula like "=HOUR(A2)*3600 + MINUTE(A2)*60 + SECOND(A2)" to convert it.

But this does not work for the **dd:hh:mm:ss** format, since day() function does not work like hour()/minute()/second() here. Could anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Those values are being recognized as text, so try splitting them, extracting the day value and the time value separately, and then convert them

Answer (score 3):

In Excel, time is expressed as days and fractions of a day.

There are `86400` seconds in one day.

It appears that your data is all text.

Text strings that include the **dd** parameter will not convert automatically; without that, it will as the result any mathematical operation.

So you can test for the error to treat the **dd** formatted strings differently

- Multiply the value by `86400 =>` number of seconds
- If there is an error, use `LEFT` to extract the **dd** portion; `MID` to extract the time portion; then add them together and multiply the summation by `86400`.

Try:

```
=IFERROR(A14*86400,(LEFT(A14,FIND(":",A14)-1)+ MID(A14,FIND(":",A14)+1,99))*86400)
```

(*If you want whole seconds, you can wrap the formula in a `ROUND` or `INT` function*)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
=IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2;":";""))=3;DAY(LEFT(A2;SEARCH(":";A2)-1))*24*3600+HOUR(RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-SEARCH(":";A2)))*3600+MINUTE(RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-SEARCH(":";A2)))*60+SECOND(RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-SEARCH(":";A2)));HOUR(A2)*3600+MINUTE(A2)*60+SECOND(A2))
```

**OPTION WITH ALL DECIMALS**: When you use SECOND, you are ignoring all decimals, that's why values like 12.9883 are being rounded to 13 seconds. If you need all decimals, you can do:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;":";""))=3;DAY(LEFT(A1;SEARCH(":";A1)-1))*24*3600+VALUE(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-SEARCH(":";A1)))*24*60*60;VALUE(A1)*24*60*60)
```

And your output will be this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the strings represent time use the [VALUE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/value-function-257d0108-07dc-437d-ae1c-bc2d3953d8c2) to convert them to a time serial number, after that apply the
[TEXT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) to convert the time serial to seconds.

Also use the `Left`, `Right` and `Substitute` functions to separate the days, time and fraction of seconds.

This formula returns the total of seconds represented in column `A`

```
= IFERROR( --TEXT( VALUE($A1), "[ss]" ),
  --TEXT( --LEFT( SUBSTITUTE( $A1, ":", REPT( " ", 25 ), 1 ), 25 )
 --TRIM( RIGHT( SUBSTITUTE( $A1, ":", REPT( " ", 25 ), 1 ), 25 ) ), "[ss]" ) )
```

This formula returns the total of seconds with decimals represented in column `A`

```
= IFERROR( --TEXT( VALUE($A1), "[ss]" )
 --RIGHT( SUBSTITUTE( $A1, ".", REPT( " ", 25 ) & ".", 1 ), 25 ),
 --TEXT( --LEFT( SUBSTITUTE( $A1, ":", REPT( " ", 25 ), 1 ), 25 )
 --TRIM( RIGHT( SUBSTITUTE( $A1, ":", REPT( " ", 25 ), 1 ), 25 ) ), "[ss]" )
 --RIGHT( SUBSTITUTE( $A1, ".", REPT( " ", 25 ) & ".", 1 ), 25 ) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to find diff in two cells of format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.ms
( ex: if result is say 1.xx then xx is milliseconds )

`=(a1-b1)*86400`

note: before using this method ensure you convert the cell where the formula is written in to numbers